# MongoDB Node.js Aggregation returns no documents when tryng to query against Date

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 2 Mongo DB collections which I am trying to write an aggregation query for. I dont get any errors, but the result is always empty and I can not figure out why. When I remove the date part out of the $match, it gives results, once I try to $lte: myDate the result data is empty although there are many documents inside that collection with updatedAt older than my passed Date object.

Note: Im using a Framework called Moralis therefore I have to replace _id in my aggregations with objectId and sometimes remove the $ beforethe operators. But like I said, without the date match it works.

This is how the collections look

**TokenBalance Collection**
*sample document*

```
{_id:"asdasdadfdf", address:"someethaddress",balance: [{symbol:"ETH", balance: 22}], updatedAt: date, createdAt: date}
```

**_AddressSyncStatus Collection**
sample document

```
{address: "someaddressstring", value: 22, updatedAt: Date, createdAt: Date}
```

Here is my aggregation

```js
const combined_tokenbalances_by_date_pipeline = (
  from_date,
  min_eth_value,
  max_eth_value
) => [
  {
    lookup: {
      from: "_AddressSyncStatus",
      localField: "address",
      foreignField: "address",
      as: "synced_address"
    }
  },
  {
    unwind: {
      path: "$synced_address"
    }
  },
  {
    match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "synced_address.value": {
            $gte: min_eth_value
          }
        },
        {
          "synced_address.value": {
            $lte: max_eth_value
          }
        },
        {
          "updatedAt": { $lte: from_date }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    sort: {
      updatedAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    group: {
      objectId: "$address",
      balance: {
        $last: "$balance"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    unwind: {
      path: "$balance"
    }
  },
  {
    group: {
      objectId: "$balance.symbol",
      count: {
        $sum: {
          $toDecimal: "$balance.balance"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    project: {
      _id: 0,
      symbol: "$_id",
      total: "$count"
    }
  }
];
```

The result when I remove the match part of the Date is like this, which I also want the same to be when checking against Date.

```
  {
   symbol:"AMD"
   total:5340885259660958307500485147118
  }
```

This is how I call the query from code

```js
const from_date = new Date(new Date().getTime()- 10 * 60000)
const result = await Parse.Cloud.run("getCombinedTokenBalances", {from_date: from_date,min_eth_value:0, max_eth_value: 100000000});
console.log(result);
```

The from_date that gets passed to the function that makes the aggregation logs out the from_date like this

```
 getCombinedTokenBalances {"from_date":"2022-03-24T10:43:49.124Z","min_eth_value":0,"max_eth_value":100000000}
```

Comment: `"updatedAt": { $lte: from_date }` - what is the value in the `from_date`? The data types of the `updatedAt` and the `from_date` must be the same for proper comparison.

Comment: I updated the initial post, see the last lines now showing how I call the function and what the from_date looks like when logging out to console.

Answer (score 0):

If your from_date is a string or number, try to compare date objects.

```js
{
  "updatedAt": { $lte: new Date(from_date) }
}
```

or try to convert your stored value to a date

```
{
 $set: {
 fixedDate: { $dateFromString: {
    dateString: "$from_date"
  } 
 }
}
```

Then do the compare on `fixedDate`

Comment: I have tried new Date(from_date) before, that gives back the same result.

Comment: post a dump of the result when you comment out the 'updatedAt'. you might not be storing as a date.  looks like you are storing it as an iso 'string'

Comment: try to convert your date field using  $dateFromString in the pipeline before you do the compare.